# Quit MySQL without it restarting on El Capitan

Tags: mysql, macos, apache, osx-elcapitan

I'm running OS X 10.11 El Capitan with its built-in server stack (Apache 2.4.16, MySQL 5.6.26).

I need to quit mysql, but killing the process immediately restarts it.

Here's what I've tried so far:

---

### Killing the process

`$ ps aux | grep mysql` to get the PID returns

```
74 49484     1   0 10:23AM ??         0:00.46 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid --port=3307
```

Then, `$ sudo kill -9 49484` kills the process, but it immediately restarts with with a higher PID.

---

### Unloading mysqld from launchd

`$ launchctl list | grep mysql` returns nothing, so there is nothing to `$ launchctl unload`

---

### Stopping the mysql server

`$ /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop` fails with "ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!" despite the fact that mysql is running and the PID file is up-to-date in /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid.

---

The above are all suggested solutions I found on Stack Overflow, none of which work for me on El Capitan. On Yosemite, simply killing the process was sufficient but with the El Capitan update, mysql is immediately restarted.

Thanks.

Comment: After you obtain the process ID of MySQL, find out what process is its parent: `ps -o ppid= -p 49484` where `49484` is the PID of your MySQL. The result will be the parent process (if any) and that way you can verify if there's a process which acts as supervisor (which keeps restarting MySQL). If you get a result back, please post again with further info. If not, I was wrong and you have gremlins :/

Comment: It's parent PID is 1 (init).

Comment: Same story here. Anyone?

Comment: If you start `mysqld` directly from command line with super user, ppid of mysqld maybe is a 1, you can stop it with top answer. If you start `mysqld` with `mysqld_safe`, you can stop it with @Mjh's comment.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What finally worked for me was stopping MySQL through the Mac System Preferences interface. That killed mysql without it coming back.

[image]

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me as well. Thank you.

Comment: Well done, this was the only thing that worked for me as well. Every time I killed the only mysql pid I could find, a new one was started.

Answer (score 9):

On `macOS Sierra`, this worked for me

Stop MySQL:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Start MySQL:

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Comment: On macOS Sierra, I used this method to stop MySQL successfully, but could not subsequently restart it via the MySQL System Preferences pane. I was only able to restart MySQL with the second command in this answer.

Comment: This worked for me (FINALLY!) with only a small difference: 

`launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql56.plist`

Answer (score 8):

On OS X El Capitan, this worked for me:

```
sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Answer (score 8):

If you used **homebrew** to install mysql, `mysqld` will keep on restarting unless you use following brew command:

```
brew services list
```

[image: brew services list output]

Get the name of service to stop and then run the following command:

```
brew services stop mysql@5.5
```

Answer (score 4):

I found that the following commands worked for me:

To Stop mysql:

```
sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

To Start mysql:

```
sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

Comment: I'm running El Capitan and I get `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 4):

On my config I found this:

```
$ cat /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true />
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mysql.mysqld</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
      <string>--user=mysql</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

You need to: change that true tag after KeepAlive to false and unload the daemon as others have suggested.
In my case that was:
    `sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist && launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist`

Once the daemon will have restarted with the new config it will not keep mysql from being shut down when you kill it from the preferences.

Answer (score 2):

As per Theory's answer, this is still effective for `Mojave`.

`sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist`

Per amacrobert, if you are facing this issue of `mysqld` continuing starting up, this is most likely due to you having `mysql` installed on the system level and by default, it will startup automatically on a computer restart.

In my situation, I was confused after a computer restart why my `docker` `mysql` container complained about an already allocated port.  After continual debugging, I remember I installed `mysql` on the system level and never restarted my computer!

Cheer.

Answer (score 0):

this stopped mysql for me on `Mac Sierra`

`sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist`