# MySQL suddenly stopped starting on OS X El Capitan 10.11.3

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp, osx-elcapitan

I'm using XAMPP, and it was working fine, but yesterday, just out of nowhere, the MySQL Database refused to start.

[image]

I'm using port `3308` because apparently another application is using port `3306`.

That's what is showing on Application log:
[image]

The odd is that on the MySQL tab under System Preferences, MySQL is shown as running.
[image]

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to stop MySQL that comes with OSX?

Comment: Yes I did, it stops but in a matter of seconds it starts again.

Comment: Here are some solutions, maybe one of them works for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909740/quit-mysql-without-it-restarting-on-el-capitan

Comment: Hey, thank you. The command line mentioned stopped the MySQL from the system preferences, however it still is not working for XAMPP. I really don't know what to do.