# Can not stop mysqld with mysqladmin

Tags: mysql

I am in MySQl8.0 on macOS. I have tried two ways to stop mysqld:

- kill this process from Activity Monitor, But It will restart immediately by itself.
  [image]
- kill this with mysqlsadmin, but still failed.[image]

From PID, I know I actually kill it, but someone restart mysqld, but I don't know which  guy restart this....

Comment: Please edit your question to include the log files of your mysql service as well as the configuration of your mysql server. As you see, there is most likely a watchdog service running which restarts the mysql server in case it crashes (as seend by the PID). Also see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124974/mysqld-keeps-automatically-restarting and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014500/macosx-autostart-mysql-on-boot

Comment: The solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32910790/8252883. It work for me. Can anyone close this question?